# An inequality for powers of reals: $a^{1/n}-b^{1/n}<(a-b)^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $a>b>0$ and let $n \in N$ satisfy $n \geq 2$.

Prove that $$a^{1/n}-b^{1/n}<(a-b)^{1/n}.$$

If we let $a=x$ and $b=x-1$, then we need to show that $f(x):=x^{1/n}-(x-1)^{1/n}$ is decreasing for $1\leq x$ (which means that $f'(x)\leq 0$ and $f$ is differentiable), and evaluate $f$ at $1$ and $a/b$.

Comment: and the problem being ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to assume that $s:=a-b=1$; the given assumptions only say $s>0$.

Keep  $s>0$ fixed for the moment and consider the function
$$f(b):=(b+s)^{1/n}-b^{1/n}\qquad(b>0)\ .$$
Then $$f'(b)={1\over n}\left((b+s)^{{1\over n}-1}-b^{{1\over n}-1}\right)<0\qquad(b>0)\ .$$
It follows that
$$f(b)<\lim_{x\to0+} f(x)=s^{1/n}\qquad(b>0)\ .$$
Since $b+s=a$ this is saying that
$$a^{1/n}-b^{1/n}<(b-a)^{1/n}\ ,$$
as claimed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Mr. Blatter. I would like to share my own work with you and need your help: $f(x)=x^{1/n} - (x-1)^{1/n}. f(1)=1. f(a/b)=(a/b)^{1/n}-(a/b-1)^{1/n}=(a^{1/n}-(a-b)^{1/n})/b^{1/n}<1.$ Then $a^{1/n}-b^{1/n}<(b-a)^{1/n}$. How can I prove that $f(x)$ is decreasing?

Comment: Apart from a typo your proof now can be finished by noting that $f'(x)<0$, since $x\mapsto x^\alpha$ is decreasing when $\alpha<0$.